# producing output of arrow keys

Tags: c, char, int, output, arrow-keys

As we know that arrow keys produces two outputs `224` and `77` or `80` or `72` or `75`.

Code 1:-

```
int main()
{
    int ch,ch1;
    ch=getch();
    ch1=getch();
    printf("%d\n",ch);
    printf("%d",ch1);
}
```

When you press `up key`it displays

```
224
72
```

Code 2:-

```
int main()
{
    char ch,ch1;
    ch=getch();
    ch1=getch();
    printf("%d\n",ch);
    printf("%d",ch1);
}
```

When you press `up key` it displays

```
-32
 72
```

My question is that, as you can see that the second output is same for both `char` and `int`, but why the first output i.e. `224` and `-32` are different with `int` and `char`.

Comment: Do you know what is the return type of `getch`?

Comment: @haccks : I think it just return the character read from keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number 224, when stored in `signed char`, overflows.

`char` typically gets considered as `signed char` and can hold values [from -128 to 127](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/1.2.html#variables). When you attempt to store a number beyond those limits, overflow occurs which causes the number to go around from the other end.

You can think of it as filling a jar with water, then emptying out the whole jar when you fill the whole jar, and then go on filling whatever you are left. In this case, you are filling a `char` variable with `224`... So;

- 224 first fills 127,
- then you are left with 224 - 127 = 97,
- one more (97 - 1 = 96) and you are at -128 now,
- you end up at -128 + 96 = -32

Answer (score 1):

That's because the range of char is -128 to 127. Which means you can assign positive values of range 0 to 127 and negative values of -1 to -128.

Answer (score 0):

The help/man page says that getch returns int: not char.

Depending on the compiler, char can default to either a signed char or an unsigned char.  The range for a signed char is -128..127, an unsigned char 0..255.  In this case, it is a signed char.  The Microsot compiler has a compiler switch for this.

If 224 is assigned to an unsigned char, you will get 224.  If it is assigned to an unsigned char, you will get 224-256 = -32.

Comment: please elaborate it a bit more in case of `signed char`